# intel core i5 and nvidia gforce opencl cuda platforms 0

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, games, intel, opencl

I am having trouble understanding how to get opencl and cuda work on my ubuntu installation for video games.

CPU SPEC

```
lshw -C cpu
  *-cpu                   
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 3d
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz
       slot: SOCKET 0
       size: 3323MHz
       capacity: 3800MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
       configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
```

Graphic card SPEC

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
```

nvidia cuda approved https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus approved

I have installed  Intel® SDK for OpenCL™ Applications for Linux and nvidia cuda folowing this http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation

after system reboot `clinfo` command returns folowing:

```
clinfo: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)
Number of platforms                               0
```

Why does clinfo not finding any platforms?

Comment: Well, without knowing exactly what you are asking, but you do not need `opencl` or `cuda` to play video games.